# Copy vector<char> into char*

Tags: c++, vector, char, c-strings

I'm just studying C and C++ programming.

I've searched and can't seem to find an answer that has a decent response. Of course using `<string>` is much easier but for this task I am REQUIRED to use only clib `<string.h>` functions; I'm also not allowed to use C++11 functions.

I have the 2 variables below, and want to move the contents of `buffer` into `c`.

```
vector<char> buffer;
char* c = "";
```

How can I do this easily?

---

I have this so far but it obviously doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't be here.

```
for (int b = 0; b < buffer.size(); b++)
{
    c += &buffer[b];
}
```

Comment: The question I have for you is -- why do you want to do this?  A pointer to the first element of the vector **is** a `char *`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of something that *requires* a `char*`, and won't work with a `std::vector<char>` ?

Comment: Since `c` is a pointer to a constant, it makes no sense to move anything into it. You need to do a better job of explaining your actual problem.

Comment: Are you trying to call a function that requires a `char*`?  If so, then you don't need to do any of this.  Just pass `&buffer[0]` to that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is;

```
 std::vector<char> buffer;
   // some code that places data into buffer
 char *c = new char[buffer.size()];
 std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), c);
    // use c
 delete [] c;
```

`std::copy()` is available in the standard header `<algorithm>`.

This assumes the code that places data into `buffer` explicitly takes care of inserting any trailing characters with value zero (`'\0'`) into the buffer.  Without that, subsequent usage of `c` cannot assume the presence of the `'\0'` terminator.

If you want to ensure a trailing `'\0'` is present in `c` even if `buffer` does not contain one, then one approach is;

```
 std::vector<char> buffer;
   // some code that places data into buffer
 char *c = new char[buffer.size() + 1];    // additional room for a trailing '\0'
 std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), c);
 c[buffer.size()] = '\0';
    // use c
 delete [] c;
```

One could also be sneaky and use another vector;

```
 std::vector<char> container;
   // some code that places data into buffer
 std::vector<char> v(container);   // v is a copy of container
 v.push_back('\0');    // if we need to ensure a trailing '\0'
 char *c = &v[0]

    // use c like a normal array of char
```

As long as the code that uses `c` does not do anything that will resize `v`, the usage of `c` in this case is exactly equivalent to the preceding examples.  This has an advantage that `v` will be released when it passes out of scope (no need to remember to `delete` anything) but a potential disadvantage that `c` cannot be used after that point (since it will be a dangling pointer).

Answer (score 2):

First, allocate space for the data by assigning `c = new char[buffer.size()];`

Then use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the data: `memcpy(c, buffer.data(), buffer.size())`

Your `for` loop would work in place of `memcpy`, too.

Also note that if `vector<char>` stays in place all the time when you use `char*`, and you are allowed to change the content of the vector, you could simply use the data behind the vector with a simple assignment, like this:

```
char *c = buffer.data();
```

> I'm noticing some weird behavior when I create my char* of the given size is that it creates it bigger with some random `"hereýýýý««««««««"` values after my word

It looks like you do need a null-terminated C string after all. In this case you need to allocate one extra character at the end, and set it to zero:

```
char *c = new char[buffer.size()+1];
memcpy(c, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
c[buffer.size()] = 0;
```

Comment: You forgot to mention about the null character at the end.

Comment: OP never said it should become a null-terminated C string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: true, although OP doesn't know what he's talking about given that it's not possible to "move the contents of the buffer into `c`" as requested ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight wont operations on strings without a terminating null character lead to memory leaks

Comment: @Nivetha Absence of null terminator creates issues only when you pass such strings to functions that expect null terminated strings (e.g. `strcpy` or `strlen`). You wouldn't get memory leaks, though - you'd get undefined behavior for reading past the end of allocated region.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thank you! That works great. I failed to mention in my OP that I'm just studying C and C++ programming. I'm noticing some weird behaviour when I create my char* of the given size is that it creates it bigger with some random "hereýýýý««««««««" values after my word (i have copied in 'here' already. How can I get rid of this? I've done only as your code states.

Comment: Edit - Fixed it by adding 1 to the buffer.size() and manually adding a null terminator at the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
vector<char> buffer;
//I am assuming that buffer has some data
char *c = new char[buffer.size()+1];

for( int i=0; i<buffer.size(); i++ )
   c[i] = buffer[i];
c[i] = '\0';

buffer.clear();
```